# Не отображается видео реклама в AdMob

Tags: java, android, admob

Реализовал межстраничный показ рекламы AdMob. Показ графической рекламы работает отлично, но постоянно выдает ошибку:

```
[MediaCodecRenderer] Failed to initialize codec supporting video/avc java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
```

Ошибка возникает в строчке

```
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
```

В документации AdMob не нашел ничего про кодеки для отображения видео.

Метод, в котором вызываю рекламный пост:

```
public static void getAdMobPost(Context context){

    // Создаём межстраничное объявление
    InterstitialAd interstitial = new InterstitialAd(context);
    interstitial.setAdUnitId(PublicConstants.ADMOB_ID);

    //Создаём запрос к AdMob
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();

    // Начинаем загружать объявление
    interstitial.loadAd(adRequest);

    if (interstitial.isLoaded()) {
        interstitial.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Не совсем ясно как вы запрашиваете видео-рекламу. Проясните сей момент.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Добавил метод с вызовом рекламы

Comment: Вы имеете в виду, что эти строки появляются в логах просто, а не прерывают выполнение программы ошибкой?.. И уточните - у вас точно все библиотеки и GooglePlayServices на телефоне обновлены?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб да, эти строки появляются просто в логах, но после этого, функционал приложения сильно тупит.  А по поводу библиотек и GooglePlayServices я не знаю, где это глянуть? В зависимостях вносил `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.4.0'`

Comment: Ну, библиотека, вроде, последняя. `GooglePlayServices` - это приложение от гугла на телефоне. Через него много что работает. Возможно оно не обновлено. И ещё вопрос - это на всех девайсах/эмуляторах или лишь на каком-то из них?..

Comment: @ЮрийСПб GooglePlayServices обновлен (Версия 8.4.89). Это на 1 девайсе (На других не тестил), на эмуляторе почему то не грузит рекламу вообще.

Comment: Т.е. все либы и приложения на девайсе последние и видео-реклама не показывается? Не показывается в смысле пытается, но у неё не получается или просто среди рекламы ни разу видео-реклама не показалась? А на эмуляторе... Ну, может AdMob научился определять эмулятор и не крутит там рекламу?..

Comment: @ЮрийСПб На эмуляторе вообще не показывает рекламу. Тестил на 2 девайсах и ни на одном не показывало видео. Потому и заподозрил неладное, после чего в логах нашел эту ошибку.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, у меня подобная ошибка в логах появляется, но я гружу простой BANNER/SMART_BANNER, видео реклама мне не нужна. Вы не знаете, как выключить/запретить запросы на этот вид рекламы ?

Comment: @web_alex, лично я не обращаю внимания на подобные вещи. Возможно либа просто пытается что-то проверить на девайсе, а не скачать видео...

Comment: Насколько я знаю видео показывает RevardedVideo - или что то на подобий а у вас Interstitial, вот вам  [ссылка](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/google-admob-ads-sdk/android/k-kVwVu2XBc), а вот ещё одна [ссылка](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42787360/admob-reward-video-ads-dont-work-with-test-devices/42790157)

Comment: Я бы вообще отказался от использования Admob в пользу Appodeal. Этот рекламный сервис гораздо проще в имплементации, приносит бОльший доход, и работает совместно с Admob.

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка, связанная с `MediaCodecRenderer` и `video/avc`, указывает на проблему с инициализацией кодека для видео. Это может быть вызвано несовместимостью кодеков устройства с форматами, которые используются в рекламном видео.

Чтобы решить эту проблему, вы можете попробовать следующие варианты:

1. **Обновите библиотеки AdMob:**
   Убедитесь, что у вас установлена последняя версия библиотек AdMob и Google Play Services в вашем проекте. Обновление этих библиотек может решить проблемы совместимости.
2. **Используйте другие форматы объявлений:**
   Возможно, ваши текущие объявления используют формат, который не поддерживается на некоторых устройствах. Попробуйте использовать другие форматы объявлений, например, баннеры или нативные объявления, чтобы увидеть, изменится ли ситуация.
3. **Обработайте ошибку в коде:**
   В вашем коде добавьте блок try-catch для обработки возможных исключений:

   ```java
   try {
       AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
   } catch (Exception e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
       // Обработайте ошибку по своему усмотрению
   }
   ```
4. **Проверьте настройки кодеков устройства:**
   В редких случаях проблема может быть связана с настройками кодеков на устройстве пользователя. Убедитесь, что на их устройствах установлены и актуальны кодеки для видео.

Если ни одно из вышеперечисленного не решает проблему, может быть полезно обратиться в поддержку Google AdMob или проверить форумы сообщества для обмена опытом с другими разработчиками, которые могли столкнуться с похожей проблемой.

Comment: [Почему публикация ответов созданных GPT и ChatGPT недопустима?](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy)

Answer (score 0):

Ваш код вполне функциональный, но есть место для улучшений и предотвращения потенциальных проблем. Вот улучшенный вариант с комментариями:

```java
public static void showInterstitialAd(Context context) {
    // Создаем межстраничный объявление (InterstitialAd)
    InterstitialAd interstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(context);
    
    // Устанавливаем идентификатор блока объявлений AdMob
    interstitialAd.setAdUnitId(PublicConstants.ADMOB_ID);
    
    // Строим запрос для объявления (AdRequest)
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    
    // Загружаем объявление с запросом
    interstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);
    
    // Проверяем, загружено ли объявление
    if (interstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
        // Показываем объявление
        interstitialAd.show();
    } else {
        // Можно добавить обработку случая, когда объявление не загружено
        // Например, можно попробовать загрузить его еще раз или предпринять другие действия
        Log.d("AdMob", "Interstitial ad was not loaded.");
    }
}
```

Изменения:

1. Добавлены более осмысленные имена переменных и методов для улучшения читаемости кода.
2. Добавлено логирование в случае, если объявление не загружено, чтобы обеспечить лучшую отладку.

Comment: [Почему публикация ответов созданных GPT и ChatGPT недопустима?](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy)